# How to find the index of a tag that contains certain bold text in beautifulsoup?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

In HTML, I would like to locate the index of a tag containing the bold text "risk factors". My files are not in the same format, but they share some similarities. Here are some examples:

```
<TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt; background: transparent; color: #000000">
<TR valign="top">
    <TD nowrap width="5%"><B>Item&nbsp;1A.</B></TD>
    <TD width="1%">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="94%"><B>Risk Factors</B></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

or

```
<DIV align="left" style="font-size: 11.5pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff; margin-top: 12pt; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; ">
<B><FONT color="#002868">Item&nbsp;1A.</FONT> <BR>
 Risk Factors</B>
</DIV>
```

or

```
<DIV align="left" style="font-size: 11pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff;">
<B><I>Risk Factors</I></B>
</DIV>
```

Notice that in the last example, the <B> tag does not contain the text directly, but via the <I> tag. I have to restrict to bold text because other tags may contain irrelevant text containing non-bold "risk factors".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right: you want to find parent `<div>` or `<table>` tag, where the tag `<b>` that contains string "Risk Factors":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = '''
<TABLE width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt; background: transparent; color: #000000">
<TR valign="top">
    <TD nowrap width="5%"><B>Item&nbsp;1A.</B></TD>
    <TD width="1%">&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="94%"><B>Risk Factors</B></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>


<DIV align="left" style="font-size: 11.5pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff; margin-top: 12pt; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; ">
<B><FONT color="#002868">Item&nbsp;1A.</FONT> <BR>
 Risk Factors</B>
</DIV>

<DIV align="left" style="font-size: 11pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff;">
<B><I>Risk Factors</I></B>
</DIV>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'b' and 'risk factors' in t.get_text().lower()):
    print(tag.find_previous(['div', 'table']))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 10pt; background: transparent; color: #000000" width="100%">
<tr valign="top">
<td nowrap="" width="5%"><b>Item 1A.</b></td>
<td width="1%">  </td>
<td width="94%"><b>Risk Factors</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div align="left" style="font-size: 11.5pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff; margin-top: 12pt; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; ">
<b><font color="#002868">Item 1A.</font> <br/>
 Risk Factors</b>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div align="left" style="font-size: 11pt;color: #000000; background: #ffffff;">
<b><i>Risk Factors</i></b>
</div>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```